# No access to notebook variables in ipython cell_magic

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to do some manipulation of a ROOT file in an ipython notebook (ROOT here is CERN's ROOT data analysis program with a python interface). One of ROOT's annoying features is that it often sends output directly to stdout instead of returning such output as a string. In order to have this output appear as a result in an ipython notebook, I wrote a little `cell_magic` that:

- Tells ROOT to redirect stdout to a file
- Runs the python command in the cell
- Turns off ROOT's output redirection
- Reads the file and prints the contents

Here's my little cell magic code

```
import tempfile
import ROOT
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic

@register_cell_magic
def rootprint(line, cell):
  """Capture Root stdout output and print in ipython notebook."""

  with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmpFile:

    ROOT.gSystem.RedirectOutput(tmpFile.name, "w")
    exec cell
    ROOT.gROOT.ProcessLine("gSystem->RedirectOutput(0);")
    print tmpFile.read()
```

If I put this code into an ipython notebook cell and execute it, then this works great. For example,

```
In [53]: f = ROOT.TFile('myRootFile.root')   # Load the Root file


In [54]: %%rootprint
         f.ls()  # Show the contents of the ROOT file

         ... f.ls() output appears here - yay! ...
```

Ordinarily the output of `f.ls()` goes to stdout and does not appear as the result of the cell. But with this cell magic the output does appear in the cell result! It's awesome!

BUT, if I put the cell magic code into a module, then it doesn't work. For example, I put that code above into `ipythonRoot.py` and do `import ipythonRoot.py` in the notebook. When I try to run the `%%rootprint` cell above I get an error saying that `f` is not defined. I tried changing the `exec` line to be `exec cell in globals()` but that didn't help.

Is there a way to do this? Also, is there a better way to write the `cell_magic` function (e.g. should I return the output instead of printing it)? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5):

So I figured this out by looking at the IPython code, specifically IPython/core/magics/execution.py had some nice hints. Here's my new module

```
import tempfile
import ROOT
from IPython.core.magic import (Magics, magics_class, cell_magic)

@magics_class
class RootMagics(Magics):
  """Magics related to Root.

      %%rootprint  - Capture Root stdout output and show in result cell
  """

    def __init__(self, shell):
      super(RootMagics, self).__init__(shell)

  @cell_magic
  def rootprint(self, line, cell):
    """Capture Root stdout output and print in ipython notebook."""

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmpFile:

      ROOT.gSystem.RedirectOutput(tmpFile.name, "w")
      ns = {}
      exec cell in self.shell.user_ns, ns
      ROOT.gROOT.ProcessLine("gSystem->RedirectOutput(0);")
      print tmpFile.read()

# Register
ip = get_ipython() 
ip.register_magics(RootMagics)
```

Note the use of the `Magics` class and the `shell` attribute that holds, among others things, the notebook name space. This can be regularly imported and it works fine.

Comment: Note that there's a shortcut - if you use the IPython instance (passed to `__init__` as `shell`), you can call `shell.ex(cell)` to execute the code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the magic/alias/user namespace are separate. doing an 'import' will not interfere with the magic/alias namespace. 
this is the reason why there is the %load_ext  magic, but you have to define your entry point. [Example with R magic].(https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/extensions/rmagic.py#L617).

Also I would suggest looking as [capture magic](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L1059) that does capture stdout/err without temporary files.

Once this works you can also add you extension to [the extension index](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Extensions-Index)

Comment: Thanks for the good hints! One problem with Root is that it does it's own handling of stdout/err, so I don't think there's a way around telling it to redirect to a file.